# C# Timer and synchrononization primitives

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking

I have a simple code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Random rng = new Random();
    List<int> list = new List<int>();
    static object lockObject = new object();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lock (lockObject)
        {
            foreach (int number in list) //Exception appears here
                if (number > 10)
                    list.Remove(number);
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lock (lockObject)
        {
            list.Add(rng.Next(20));
        }
    }
}
```

This code doesn't work: sometimes `foreach` statement throws System.InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified. That means that `lock` statement doesn't work. I tried replacing it with `Semaphore` object with no effect.

How can I ensure different segments of code does't modify `list` at one time? Why `lock` and `Semaphore` doesn't work in this code?

**UPD:**
I haven't seen so obvious mistake, sorry. I thought the exception was caused by insertion while `foreach`, and haven't noticed `list.Remove(number);`. Thanks for your answers!

Comment: You cannot modify a collection while iterating over it.

Comment: @dcg I know. I want to know how to ensure that collection won't be modified while I iterate over it.

Comment: @AndrewR you ensure it, by not doing it?

Comment: I haven't seen so obvious mistake, sorry. I thought the exception was caused by insertion while  `foreach`, and haven't noticed `list.Remove(number);`. Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot modify a collection while iterating over it.

So a very simple one liner to do what you want, would be:

```
list.RemoveAll(x => x > 10);
```

Answer (score 3):

The exception doesn't have anything to do with Threads or locking. It is because you are modifying the collection in a `foreach` loop. Do not do that. Instead use a simple `for` loop.

Something like:

```
for (int i = list.Count - 1; i > -1; i--)
{
    if (number > 10)
    {
        if (list[i] == number)
        {
            list.RemoveAt(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The iteration should be done from the last item till the first, so you don't get in trouble with indexes.

Comment: I think you need to use i--, not i++ ;)

Comment: I believe the condition inside the for is `if (list[i]>10){list.RemoveAt(i);}`, so the outter `if` around it needs to be removed.

Answer (score 2):

as was said, the problem is you're calling list.Remove() while enumerating the list. a semi-simple way to fix this without modifying much code is to create a copy of the list when you enumerate it like:

```
foreach (int number in new List<int>(list))
{
    if (number > 10) 
        list.Remove(number);
}
```